# Error: 'Answer' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "My Funny Program";

    do {
        string Answer;
        cout << "Are you stupid? (Yes/No)";
        cin >> Answer;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Perhaps you are lying?";
    }
    while (Answer == "No");

    cout << "Thank you for your honesty." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have been trying to get this code working; however, every time the error 'Answer was not declared in this scope' pops up.

Comment: Please do not put random things in the `tags` field.

Comment: It's a scope issue, look where you are declaring `Answer` and where you are using it...

Comment: So where should I put Answer?

Comment: Variables declared inside a set of braces are destroyed when execution reaches the close brace.  It might be a slight over-simplification (think `namespace`), but only slight.

Comment: You should be using `<string>` not `<string.h>`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `while` condition is outside the scope if the block itself. So the `string Answer` has to be defined outside the loop.

Style recommendation: Caps are used for classes or constants or macros. Avoid using them for variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
 do{

        string Answer;
        cout<< "Are you stupid? (Yes/No)";
        cin>>Answer;
        cout<< endl;
        cout<< "Perhaps you are lying?";

    }

    while (Answer == "No");
```

As Answer is declared inside the do-while, the while part has no idea of the existance of Answer.

You must declare Answer before the do-while

Answer (score 0):

Your `Answer` variable is currently only in scope between the `{}` where it's declared (inside the body of the loop).  You need to declare `Answer` before the loop.

```
string Answer;
do {
    cout << "Are you stupid? (Yes/No)";
    cin >> Answer;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Perhaps you are lying?";
}
while (Answer == "No");
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting program...

Declaring answer outside the do-while loop will address your problem.

```
string Answer;
do {

        cout << "Are you stupid? (Yes/No)";
        cin >> Answer;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Perhaps you are lying?";
    }
    while (Answer == "No");
```

Also you should use `<string>` instead of `<string.h>`

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
        string Answer;
        cout << "Are you stupid? (Yes/No)";
        cin >> Answer;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Perhaps you are lying?";
    }
    while (Answer == "No");
```

In `do` you declared a string variable `Answer`. Then the `Answer` was pushed into the stack, however, when the procedure encount `}`, the variable will be poped up, which means, in `while` statement, `Answer` has been freed, and the compiler consider `Answer` as a un-defined variable.